# Search and SortByColumns barely works on PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

i have a problem on my PowerApps app, my formula is like this :
[List's formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eek9u.png)

`SortByColumns(Search('serviceInterventions (capvision/ris/v2.0)'; TextSearchBox1.Text; "name"; "no"); "no"; If(SortDescending1; SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending))`

it doesn't search in two columns in the same time and it doesn't sort at all the only thing that works is when i search in a single column ("no" or "name" both work separately)

the columns are the right ones how can i do to fix this or at least test the potential errors i made ?